# Iterating through @Model in html5 <script>

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm trying to iterate through a list of objects created in my backend.

I have passed the object to my .cshtml file and I'm able to access it with @Model.myData and have copied it to a local list.
However when I try to iterate through it in my `<script>` I'm running into trouble.

I tried the following:

```
//roughly what im trying to do.
for (var index = 0; index < @Model.ChartLines.Count; index++) {

    for (int jindex = 0; jindex < Model.ChartLines[index].Points.Count; jindex++) {

        someservice.add(@Model.ChartLines[index].Points[Jindex].X);
    }
}
```

My problem is now that it refuses to let me use an index variable to access the position of myGraphData. I've tried some workarounds but I'm not getting it right.

Does anyone have a protip or something to go on in I want to iterate a list created outside the `<script>` in my cshtml file?

I'm fairly new to frontend webdev and come from a background of games so anything that could help me wrap my head around this would be awesome!

Comment: "*it refuses to let me use a index variable to acess the position*" doesn't sounds as precide problem definition. Can you show *exact* error text? And what is the type of `Model.ChartLines`?

Comment: Let's be clear here. `@Model` as such exists on server side (host) only, during the process of rendering the view with Razor engine. `<script>` content is javascript, which lives and gets executed on a client side (browser), after server is done and sent the response to the client. Mixing these is incorrect and impossible.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - The ChartLines object is a custom one that contains a few lists that contains lists of postions that im trying to use to render a graph.

Comment: @Andrei - How would you suggest i go round to use the object in a script? Any other way or resources that you'd suggest me looking it to?

I tried to use the ViewData["somename"+index] aswell to store the data from my backend and then use it in my script but it also proved to be an inaccurate.

Comment: Render the object to JSON, then use that.